# MySQL 5.5 - How to get row count while Table is locked during insert

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am currently inserting about 2 million rows and I need to monitor the progress of row inserts. The table is locked at the beginning of the insert operation. Is there a way I can find out the number of rows added or maybe an indicative number?

Comment: Why are you locking the table?

Comment: @horse - mysqldump locked the table

Comment: If you're using InnoDB you can run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` periodically and take a look at `ROW OPERATIONS` section specifically at line `Number of rows inserted XX, updated YY, deleted ZZ, read RR`

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this procedure but not tested with locks applied.

1. before insert find row count.
2. apply lock for insert.
3. find `rows` (row count value) from `show table status from your_db_name where name='tbl_name'`.
4. find the difference between new row count and from the former one.

Comment: Table status show 0 rows. Processlist shows rows being inserted.

Comment: 1. May be you started on an empty table. 2. May be it is waiting for a commit. 3. Check with (*peterm's comment*)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717072/mysql-5-5-how-to-get-row-count-while-table-is-locked-during-insert#comment31035112_20717072]